# Can't to read markdown while doing crud in markdown format using toast editor in React

Tags: reactjs, toast

I am implementing crud in React using json-server.

When I post it in markdown in the toast editor, it seems that the input is in markdown format in the console, but when reading it, the markdown format is applied properly and it is not read.

[When  post it in markdown in the toast editor, it seems that the input is in markdown format in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muCxL.png)
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muCxL.png)

[When reading from the page, it is displayed with nothing applied as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TTHP.png)

Currently,  POST in WritePost.jsx, it will be saved in data.json. And I am reading data from DetailPost.jsx.

```
//Write.jsx

export default function Write() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleCategoryChange = event => {
    setCategory(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleTitleChange = event => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleSave = () => {
    const editorInstance = editorRef.current.getInstance();
    const markdownContent = editorInstance.getMarkdown();

    const postData = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      category,
      title,
      date: new Date().toLocaleString('en-KR'),
      content: markdownContent,
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/posts', postData)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Post submitted:', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error submitting post:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <CommnunityPageWrapper>
        <OutletContainer>
          <CategorySelect>
            <select value={category} onChange={handleCategoryChange}>
              <option value="notice">공지사항</option>
              <option value="free">자유게시판</option>
            </select>
          </CategorySelect>
          <TitleInput
            value={title}
            onChange={handleTitleChange}
            placeholder="제목을 입력해주세요"
          />
          <UserShowBodyWrapper></UserShowBodyWrapper>
          <ManagementComponentsContainer>
            <UserShowBodyWrapper>
              <WritePost editorRef={editorRef} />
            </UserShowBodyWrapper>
          </ManagementComponentsContainer>
          <button onClick={handleSave}>Submit Post</button>
        </OutletContainer>
      </CommnunityPageWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
//WritePost.jsx

export default function WritePost({ editorRef }) {
  return (
    <>
      <RequestShowBody>
        <ListTable>
          <ListBody>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}></h2>
            <Editor
              ref={editorRef}
              height="500px"
              initialEditType="markdown"
              previewStyle="vertical"
            />
          </ListBody>
        </ListTable>
      </RequestShowBody>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
//DetailPost.jsx
export default function DetailPost() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { posts } = useSelector(state => state.posts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const params = useParams();

  const foundData = posts.find(posts => {
    return posts.id == params.id;
  });
  console.log(foundData);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPost());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <DetaileWrapper>
        <OutletContainer>
          <ManagementComponentsContainer>
            <UserShowBodyWrapper>
              <RequestShowBody></RequestShowBody>
              <ListTable>
                <ListBody>
                  <ReactMarkdown>{foundData?.content}</ReactMarkdown>
                </ListBody>
              </ListTable>
            </UserShowBodyWrapper>
          </ManagementComponentsContainer>
        </OutletContainer>
      </DetaileWrapper>
      {/* <StTitle dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: foundData.content }} /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```